# Distribution over $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, p-adic-number-theory

A distribution over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is defined as an "additive" map $\mu$ s.t.
$\mu(\mathbb{Z}_p)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\mu(i+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$.
But now if i want define a distribution over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ what is the " additivity" that this map should have? I think something like:

For every $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$,  for every $N \in\mathbb{Z} $ then  $\mu(x+ p^N\mathbb{Z}_p)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\mu(x+ip^N+p^{N+1}\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Thank you for suggestion and references!

Comment: Sure. And (since there is a basis of open sets that are compacts ?) distributions on the metric space $p^N\mathbb{Z}_p,|.|_p$ are finite measures