# About the group structure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to ask a (simple?)question: if I consider the field of p-adic numbers
$\mathbb{Q}_p$ and consider the subgroup $p^N\mathbb{Z}_p$ in which $N$ can be negative also, then the index of the group $\mathbb{Q}_p/p^N\mathbb{Z}_p$
is already $N$?
I think yes because I think it exists the factorisation also for $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ 
$$
  x+p^N\mathbb{Z}_p= \cup^{p-1}_{i=0} x+ ip^N +p^{N+1}\mathbb{Z}_p
$$
Thanks for answering!!!

Comment: The index of $p^N\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not $N$, but infinite.  Just look at $p^{-j}$ for $j>-N$.

Comment: So the decomposition above is wrong?

Comment: There is a decomposition of *multiplicative groups*
$$\Bbb{Q}_p^*=\langle p\rangle \times\Bbb{Z}_p^*,$$ where the first factor consists of all integer powers of $N$. May be your source is referring to that decomposition?

Comment: If you are thinking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2942323/11619) then the idea is that for each $N$ any coset of $p^N\Bbb{Z}_p$ is the disjoint union of $p$ cosets of the smaller subgroup $p^{N+1}\Bbb{Z}_p$. But, as $M\to-\infty$ the number of cosets of $p^{N}\Bbb{Z}_p$ in a coset of $p^M\Bbb{Z}_p$ grows without a bound.

Comment: Ok, i see thanks for the answer